# Change the border coloring of window

Tags: colors, window, fltk

I am trying to create a window with custom coloring.  I can see how to change the background color of the window when using something like FL_BORDER_BOX ([how to change the background color of Fl_Window by pressing Fl_Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056935/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-fl-window-by-pressing-fl-button)), but I can not find out how to change the border color from black.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

This is using C/C++ and FLTK btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using FL_BORDER_BOX, use FL_BORDER_FRAME.  The foreground colour of the frame can be changed.

```
Fl_Box changeling = new Fl_Box(10, 10, 100, 20);
changeling.box(FL_BORDER_FRAME);
changeling.color(FL_RED);
```

A list of the box types can be found in http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.1/common.html under **Box Types**

**EDIT**
If you wish to have a different colour inside, then draw two boxes

```
int x = 10, y = 10, w = 180, h = 100;
Fl_Box box(x, y, w, h);
box.box(FL_BORDER_FRAME);
box.color(FL_BLUE, FL_RED);
Fl_Box inner(x + 1, y + 1, w - 2, h - 2);
inner.box(FL_FLAT_BOX);
inner.color(FL_YELLOW);
```

Comment: Thanks cup! I suppose I can then just fill the background in using fl_draw_box() or similar...

Comment: Might be better to draw a box within a box.  I've modified the answer.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks again cup!